# Unable to zip folder and download it with PHP

Tags: php, zip

I'm using the following code, trying to zip a folder and download it, from the browser.

Error:

```
Warning: ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /var/www/html/functions.php on line 316
```

This is the error. It repeats for every file in folder. Using print_r i can see that the files are being read.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. PHP-ZIP Extension is correctly installed.

```
root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:/home/ubuntu# apt-get install php-zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-zip is already the newest version (2:7.4+75).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

Code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$dir = '/var/www/html/admissoes_geradas/'.$nome.'/';
createZip($zip,$dir);
$zip->close();
```

Function:

```
function createZip($zip,$dir){
  if (is_dir($dir)){

    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
       while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
            
         // If file
         if (is_file($dir.$file)) {
            
            if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
 
               $zip->addFile($dir.$file);
            }
         }else{
            // If directory
            if(is_dir($dir.$file) ){

              if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                // Add empty directory
                $zip->addEmptyDir($dir.$file);

                $folder = $dir.$file.'/';
 
                // Read data of the folder
                createZip($zip,$folder);
              }
            }
 
         }
 
       }
       closedir($dh);
     }
  }
}
```

My intention is to zip the entire "$dir" and download it from the browser.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does an error occur? Does it not display anything?

Comment: As the other question asked do you get an error message? 
Without anything else I would heavily suspect that there is a permission error where the user owning the process are not allowed to write to the directory you are saving the file too

Comment: Where's the bit which is supposed to send it for downloading?

Comment: Thank you for the answers.

Warning: ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /var/www/html/functions.php on line 316

This is the error. It repeats for every file in folder. 

Using print_r i can see that the files are being read.

Comment: Edit the question if you have more info, don't hide it in the comments. That also puts the question back at the top of the feed for its tags

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. Did it.

Comment: Make sure if the zip extension is setup/installed in your server.

Comment: @HafizAmeerHamza Yes, i've checked. It seems right.

root@ip-xxx:/home/ubuntu# apt-get install php-zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-zip is already the newest version (2:7.4+75).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.